# How can I validate more than one checkbox on submission?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, checkbox

I have two sets of checkboxes, named pizzaBase and pizzaTopping. I want to validate my form so that on submission at-least 1 base and topping must be selected.

```
function main() {
    var form = document.getElementById('formname');
    form.addEventListener('submit', validate);
}

function validate(event) {
    var form = document.getElementById('formname');
    if(!form.pizzaBase.checked) {
        alert("select a base");
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    else if(!form.pizzaTopping.checked) {
        alert("select topping");
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

### Problems

1. Only first if statement works.
2. Form submits true if checkbox is checked and then unchecked before
   submission.
3. Doesn't validate, doesn't work.

Where am I going wrong?

Thank you GG for pointing out JS is working, I have HTML below if someone wouldn't mind correcting me. I basically have two identical versions of the below code, one for bases and the other toppings.

**

### HTML

**

```
 <section>
        <h2> Bases </h2>
                <p><input type="checkbox" name="pizzaBase" data-price="1.00" data-human-desc = "Small" value="Small"> Small   (£1.00) </p>
                <p><input type="checkbox" name="pizzaBase"data-price="1.50" data-human-desc = "Medium" value="Medium">  Medium   (£1.50) </p>
                <p><input type="checkbox" name="pizzaBase" data-price="2.50" data-human-desc = "Large"value="Large">  Large   (£2.50) </p>
                <p><input type="checkbox" name="pizzaBase" data-price="3.50" data-human-desc = "XLarge"value="XLarge">  XLarge   (£3.50) </p>
                </section>
```

Not sure if I should ask a separate question here, but this is my messy HTML. Is it the sections? I was trying to split each set of check boxes (bases, toppings) into two separate sections so used this tag.

Any ideas?

Comment: The HTML should use fieldset/length instead of section/h2 and you should use label elements for your labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have multiple inputs with the same name, `form.elementName` will be an array-like list of elements.

The list won't have a `checked` property. Each item within it will.

You need to loop over the list and check to see if any of the elements are checked.

```
function areAnyChecked(list) {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].checked) { 
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

if(! areAnyChecked(form.pizzaBase)) {
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I just implemented the loop and sectioned the form using field-sets and it works! I am new to this site, Should I vote delete or is there a way to mark as 'answered'.

Comment: See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)